# How to come out of an if condition and land in else condition that is out of it?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am working on some code where I have a specific requirement.

```
if(condition){
  if(condition){

  }else{
    //if comes here then goto previous else
  }
}else{
   // come here if it goes to upper else part.
}
```

Comment: That's not how Javascript (nor any language I know of) works. You'll need to change the logic flow if you want this behaviour

Comment: Also note that this has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery (as it's a framework). It's a pure Javascript question, so I've changed the title and re-tagged it

Comment: It is actually unclear what you want to achieve. You will never go to the second else because if `condition` is true, then the first `if` will result into true as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not really make sense if the 2 else blocks have the same logic, but if they are different then outsource in a function:

```
function sameLogic(){
    // same code
}

if(condition){ 

    // or maybe some extra code here?
    $someCode = 'hy';

    if(condition){

    }
    else{ 

        // some other code here?
        $yourCode = 'someting';
        sameLogic();

    } 
}
else{  

    // no other code
    sameLogic();

}
```

If its not like this example, see the answer from Neil N

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this in a single if statement.  Just join your conditions with a boolean AND operator

```
if (condition && condition)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Comment: This isn't entirely accurate if separate logic is to be executed in each of the three possible outcomes.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan assuming there is no code between his if statements, and his inner else ONLY wants to go to the other else... then this solution is perfectly accurate.